# Powershell does not recognize path when asked to move files

Tags: powershell

I have a weird issue with windows powershell where a script I wrote to move files from one directory to another suddenly stopped working after months of flawless functionality. It is still a total mystery to me why it does not work anymore.

Below you will find (hopefully) all the information you need to help me out.

Help is much appreciated!

Best regards

Philip

[THE SCRIPT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJuPS.png)

Error output is something like:

**move: Could not find a part of the path.**

**CategoryInfo     : WriteError:  [Move-Item], DirectoryNotFoundException**

**FullyQualifiedErrorId : MoveFileInfoItemIOError, Microsoft.Powershell.Commands.MoveItemCommand**

Comment: Please, post the code and not an image of it.

Comment: PLEASE ... [1] post the full error text AS TEXT. [2] post the script AS TEXT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax to use move in powershell and to avoid errors like part of path is not found is to wrap the path with quotations as the following exapmle:

```
Move-Item -Path "C:\Users\Public\file.txt" -Destination "C:\Users\Username\Desktop"
```

Comment: Problem solved. I used your suggestion along with a much shorter name for my files. I believe the latter to have been the culprit actually.